# Import difficulties with read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, import

I have a csv-file with the following format:

```
0;2017-02-16 15:08:16;81,307877;;;;;;;
```

So, semi-colon as separator, date and time  and a float with decimal comma. And a bunch of semi-colons in the end.

Pandas csv_read should be a good solution for this. However, after plenty of attempts I feel rather stuck. I do not understand how to handle the ;;;'s in the end of the file and I am rather uncertain whether I understand how csv_read works when it comes to the more detailed control possibilities.

For someone using csv_read regularily, this has to be a very simple question... I hope. I have spent quite some time on it already...

One example:

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Henrik\PycharmProjects\Regforce\Kort_del_1.csv', 
encoding="latin", sep=';', decimal=',', usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

In return I get:

```
   ÿþ0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3
0      NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1      NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

I have also tried to "force" types for each of the columns with no result...???

Update:
I found an interesting post, http://pythonforengineers.com/website-visitors-part-2-dealing-with-corrupt-data/... so I downloaded the HEX-reader and found some odd things in the beginning of my input file. This seems to be the reason behind the "ÿþ0" in the table above. Cannot see it if I open it in Notebook but it is for sure in the file.

Can this be the origin to the NaN's in the file? And how do I handle it? Seems like read_csv is able to identify the existence of the columns, but I cannot get any values...?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `read_csv` in this way:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', sep=';', header=None, decimal=',', usecols=[0,1,2])
```

so reading everything and since you have semi-colons at the end you're not interested in, just consider the only first three columns.

EDIT: thanks to piRSquared comment, add `decimal=','` to the args.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is identified as being related to the input file. I did what I should have done first of all:
 - Make a new file with the same structure as the one which is to be imported and then
 - Test

With such a file, the import using read_csv took me less than one minute to set up and adjust to my needs.

So, the problem is converted to understanding the input file. There are things that can be seen with a HEX reader, which is not visible otherwise... But that is an entirely different topic.